# What are the thoughts and/or rules on posting a solution to an issue with a site?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

If you have an issue with a particular function or can't find a solution and eventually come up with a solution and think it may be helpful to other users, is it okay to post the problem and reply the solution or provide the solution all in the same post?

I just ask because I have run into situations in which I struggled on something and finally came up with a solution. When I presented that solution, other developers thought it was helpful. I know I have run into some from the other side as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely encouraged to answer your own questions, and even to post the question and immediately follow up by posting the answer Q&A style. But definitely post the answer *as an answer* (rather than part of the question).

There are already quite a few questions on the site where the asker answered their own question. I'm sure others will find it helpful.

For more see [Can I answer my own question?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in the help center.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I know that happens, but some of the SE segments frown on it. I just wanted to check.

Comment: Strange. I've never seen it frowned upon (though I do not doubt you). And it's officially encouraged and might help someone else so I say go for it!

Comment: Agreed. Thanks again.